# Discord.js v13 voice channel data is not updating

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My Slash commands are registered and they come up in discord.
Simplified version of my usage:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    console.log(interaction.member.voice.channel);

    interaction.reply('done');
});
```

When running this it will always give the ouput from when i started the bot. For example if I join a channel and then start the bot, it gives the correct output, but if i then leave the channel it gives me the same output. If I'm not in a channel when I start the bot, the output correctly is null but if i join a channel it will again still be null until i restart the bot.
Has anybody had the same problem / is my thinking wrong or does someone know a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem with the slash commands functionality. You have to add the [`GUILD_VOICE_STATES`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents) intent to your client. This lets it detect updates to voice channels such as when you leave or join.